# Android Xamarin detect started from task manager

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am currently developing an android xamarin app (android 6 and above) and I have got a problem.

Our customer wants to secure the app by a pinpad. Whenever the app is started the user has to enter a four digit pin.

We have created an activity for the pinpad. This works pretty fine, but the problem is the following:

The pinpad just opens if the app was completely killed (e.g. by the task manager ) -> **cold started**.

How can I achive that the pinpad opens if the app was in the background and reopend by the task manager for example (user pressed home button and then wants to start app again) -> **warm started.**

I've tried to do this by OnResume(), OnStart(),. But unfortunately they trigger every time an another activity (e.g. open detail view of list item) is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **IActivityLifecycleCallbacks** to listen the status.

`Application` registration `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`, such, when each activity in the app lifecycle occurs, the Application can be listening to. The number of `public void onActivityStarted(activity activity)` and `public void onActivityStopped(activity activity)` of an activity can be used to determine whether the app is in the foreground. Because when the app is in the foreground, an activity must have started onActivityStarted but not onActivityStopped, so the statistics of the number of activities opened in the app must be 1. When the app switches to the background, activityStartCount will be 0.

so write a Helper classes :

```
public class AppFrontBackHelper
{

    public static OnAppStatusListener mOnAppStatusListener;
    private LifecycleCallBack lifecycleCallBack;
    public AppFrontBackHelper()
    {

    }
    /**
     * Register status listener, only used in Application
     * @param application
     * @param listener
     */
    public void register(Application application, OnAppStatusListener listener)
    {
        mOnAppStatusListener = listener;
        lifecycleCallBack = new LifecycleCallBack();
        application.RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(lifecycleCallBack);
    }

    public void unRegister(Application application) => application.UnregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(lifecycleCallBack);

    public interface OnAppStatusListener
    {
        void onFront();
        void onBack();
    }
    public class LifecycleCallBack : Java.Lang.Object, Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
    {

        public int activityStartCount { get; private set; }

        public void OnActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        }

        public void OnActivityDestroyed(Activity activity)
        {
        }

        public void OnActivityPaused(Activity activity)
        {
        }

        public void OnActivityResumed(Activity activity)
        {
        }

        public void OnActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState)
        {
        }

        public void OnActivityStarted(Activity activity)
        {
            activityStartCount++;
            //A value from 1 to 0 indicates cutting from the background to the foreground
            if (activityStartCount == 1)
            {

                if (mOnAppStatusListener != null)
                {
                    mOnAppStatusListener.onFront();
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnActivityStopped(Activity activity)
        {
            activityStartCount--;
            //A value from 1 to 0 indicates cutting from the foreground to the background
            if (activityStartCount == 0)
            {
                //从前台切到后台
                if (mOnAppStatusListener != null)
                {
                    mOnAppStatusListener.onBack();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

then custom an **Application** and regist the listener :

```
[Application]
public class MyApplication : Application,AppFrontBackHelper.OnAppStatusListener
{
    protected MyApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        AppFrontBackHelper appFrontBackHelper = new AppFrontBackHelper();
        appFrontBackHelper.register(this, this);
    }
    public void onBack()
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "from front to back", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }



    public void onFront()
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "from back to front", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }


}
```

you could do something in the `onFront()` callback.

Comment: Thank you so much. i'm going to implement this on monday.